# How do I toggle between current frame size and maximized frame

Tags: frames

When I open emacs, the frame size is set to: width 85 and height 40.

Is there a keybinding to toggle between maximizing the frame, and going back to the previous frame size of 85 x 40

Comment: Have you tried going into and out of the full screen mode with `F11`? If you don't resize the frame, it will toggle between full screen and window with initial size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maximize the frame, but not make it take up the whole screen, you can use `toggle-frame-maximized`, which is on <kbd>M-f10</kbd> by default. <kbd>C-h f toggle-frame-maximized</kbd>:

```
toggle-frame-maximized is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`frame.el'.

It is bound to <M-f10>, ESC <f10>.

(toggle-frame-maximized &optional FRAME)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 24.4.

Toggle maximization state of FRAME.
Maximize selected frame or un-maximize if it is already maximized.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function called `toggle-frame-fullscreen` which looks to be bound to `f11` key by default.  You can use `C-h f` to call `describe-function` and put `toggle-frame-fullscreen` at the prompt.  It will tell you about how the function works and what key it is currently bound to, if any.

Comment: If OP want 'maximize' in the sense of 'make as big as possible without obscuring toolbars' etc., there's also `toggle-frame-maximized`, which is on `M-f10`

Comment: Thank you @rpluim, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @rpluim: Please submit that as an answer (comments can be deleted at any time). OP: If that's your preferred answer then you can accept it (unaccepting this answer).

Comment: I was hoping @shoshin would update his answer ☺

Comment: haha, i was going to, but didn't want to take away your credit @rplium :) i simply misread the question.